# Debugging zombienet config after using hrmp channels

Tags: zombienet

I am trying to spin a zombinet with a relay chain and multiple parachains, and everything runs fine until adding the following code for opening up HRMP channels :

```
[[hrmp_channels]]
sender = 1000
recipient = 2058
maxCapacity = 8
maxMessageSize = 8000

[[hrmp_channels]]
sender = 2058
recipient = 1000
maxCapacity = 8
maxMessageSize = 8000
```

```shell
Error:       Error: Command failed with exit code 1: bash -c bin/polkadot build-spec --chain /tmp/zombie-453fa9da8398b3e0ea8a5193e4f5b29e_-40192-gUu4dLvbM9Al/rococo-local-plain.json --disable-default-bootnode  --raw > /tmp/zombie-453fa9da8398b3e0ea8a5193e4f5b29e_-40192-gUu4dLvbM9Al/rococo-local-raw.json
Error: 
   0: Other: Error parsing spec file: invalid type: null, expected u32 at line 275 column 18
```

I am not sure how to proceed.. I am using the latest zombienet release (1.3.63).

Answer (score 2):

thanks for using `zombienet` and open this questions. The keys to set an `hrmp` channel are `max_capacity` and `max_message_size` (you can check the [docs](https://paritytech.github.io/zombienet/network-definition-spec.html#hrmp_channels-array-of-objects). With this change the network should spin as expected.

As reference, this should works

```
[[hrmp_channels]]
sender = 1000
recipient = 2058
max_capacity = 8
max_message_size = 8000

[[hrmp_channels]]
sender = 2058
recipient = 1000
max_capacity = 8
max_message_size = 8000
```

Thanks!

p.s: Can you open an issue in the [repo](https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet) to improve this config error reporting?